# App crashes due to TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-orientation

My app crashes due to a `TextView`. It works as long as the device doesn't change its orientation. If I remove the TextView and rotate the device everything works fine but with the TextView it doesn't.
I have 2 layouts for portrait and layout-land.
They look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/text_time"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And some code:

```
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

then in another method I set the text:

```
mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mTextView.setText("Text");
```

and that's it. So do you have any suggestions why that doesn't work?

I get the following error:

```
01-07 17:14:28.117 12890-12890/k.com.kamera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: k.com.kamera, PID: 12890
                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment BasicFragmentVideo{e87fd0c} not attached to Activity
                                                                       at android.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:805)
                                                                       at android.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:840)
                                                                       at k.com.kamera.BasicFragmentVideo$5$1$1.run(BasicFragmentVideo.java:483)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: use setretaininstance in fragment class to retain the fragment instance

Comment: Can you provide any working code?

Answer (score 0):

Each time orientation changes, you're creating a new instance of Fragment. And only one of them is actually attached to the Activity. Try this

```
 public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    TestFragment testFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
        attachFragment(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void attachFragment(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
           testFragment = new TestFragment();
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.camera_frame, testFragment,     "testFragment").commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else {
      testFragment =  (TestFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("testFragment");
    }
}
```

call `setRetainInstance(true)` in your fragment's  `onCreateView`() or `onActivityCreated`()

Comment: I add the `Fragment` this way: android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.camera_frame, fragInfo);
                transaction.commit();

Comment: you are using `import android.app.fragment`?

Comment: Yes. It works as long as the device doesn't rotate so I don't know how to fix that

Comment: in your activity where you are opening the fragment try passing the activity's `savedInstanceState`  and check like my code...it will work

Comment: also change your fragment transaction code to add the `testFragment` tag

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. I still get the same error

Comment: try `commitAllowingStateLoss` instead of `commit`..see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Use setRetainInstance as true  in fragment this will retain the fragment instance when orientation happens and now in Acitivty inside onCreate check for your fragment instance and add

Comment: Ok but if I set that to true, the text view doesn't exist anymore. Do you know how to fix it?